# Multiple parametric recursive types and type inference in Julia

Tags: julia

I have created a data structure of this sort

```
abstract type Node end

struct Tree{A <: Node, B <: Node} <: Node
    a::A
    b::B
end
```

This type of structure allows me to conveniently address nodes of a tree by the type of the children.

As an example I can have

```
struct Character <: Node
    c::Char
end
```

and make a specialized method that recognizes a tree with two `Character` children

```
function test(node::Tree{Character, Character}) end
```

But I could also potentially define a function like

```
function test(node::Tree{Tree{Character, Character}, Tree}) end
```

which address a `Tree` with the leftmost branch containing two `Character` and an arbitrary `Tree` on the right one.

My implementation dispatches many methods in a similar fashion.

This type of structure works, but for quite large trees I have noticed some slowdowns, especially when trying to determine the types using `typeof`. Is this pattern considered efficient? If not, is there a way to make it more efficient?

Comment: What do you mean by "addressing nodes by the type"? Can you please add your implementation and what you're actually measuring?

Comment: Edited, I could not add pieces of the implementation as that would obfuscate the scope of the question, therefore I added two examples. I am interested only if this specific approach to recursive types could be inefficient.

Comment: Oh, the stuff you added isn't obfuscating at all, it makes it a good question. How did you time? I suspect that the effect you measure only occurs the first time you call the function, due to compilation; after that, it should be quite fast. Try BenchmarkTools.

Comment: BenchmarkTools reports indeed a high maximum time and a low minimum, median and mean time on all of the functions. The maximum time is always registered in the first run, the problem is that it seems that whenever I change the input argument of a function dispatched in a similar fashion to the one I showed, it seems to always report higher. This is likely because changing the structure of the tree changes the structure of the type itself, which the compiler tries to optimize the function on.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more it sounds like a dirty hack. The only problem is that I cannot think of any real alternatives that are as convenient as writing the methods in the way I did for `test`.

Answer (score 1):

There will be probably many proposals for tree definition depending on a particular scenario. However, for sure you want to avoid recursively nested type structure that leads to poor performance.

Here is my proposal. This binary tree can hold any data of type `T`

```
struct Tree{T}
    val::T
    a::Union{Tree{T}, Nothing}
    b::Union{Tree{T}, Nothing}
end

Tree(val::A) where A=Tree{A}(val,nothing,nothing)

leaf1 = Tree(4)
leaf2 = Tree(5)
subb1 = Tree(555,leaf1,leaf2)
tree = Tree(1000,subb1, Tree(888))
```

Now let us see that tree :

```
juila> dump(tree)
Tree{Int64}
  val: Int64 1000
  a: Tree{Int64}
    val: Int64 555
    a: Tree{Int64}
      val: Int64 4
      a: Nothing nothing
      b: Nothing nothing
    b: Tree{Int64}
      val: Int64 5
      a: Nothing nothing
      b: Nothing nothing
  b: Tree{Int64}
    val: Int64 888
    a: Nothing nothing
    b: Nothing nothing
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a similar approach to this one and dispatching the methods similarly in how I did in my example `test` functions?

Comment: No, because this assumes homogeneity of the data stored. Now looking at your problem again, you look for something like `StaticArrays` but oriented for trees. The issue with `StaticArrays` is that it is very fast for arrays having like 5 or 10 elements and unusable due to compiling time for arrays having few hundreds elements. Since you want to have big trees, I think that you should elaborate more on *what* you want to achieve and not *how* and perhaps than another solution could be proposed.